# Generar un código Automáticamente en C# ó SQLServer

Tags: c#, sql

quisiera hacer una consulta, quiero generar un código que sea autoincrementable, es decir si inserto un producto aparte de su Id que será su `primary key` y también autoincrementable quiero que aparte se me guarde un código que tenga la siguiente estructura "`PROD001`" y si inserto otro sea "`PROD002`" , pero que se genere automáticamente al insertar un producto. ¿Cómo podría hacer esto?. espero haberme hecho entender. Utilizó como base de datos `Sql Server` y el IDE `Visual studio 2017` con lenguaje `C#`.

Comment: Te recomiendo que leas o investigues sobre los trigger (desencadenadores) de sql server. Creo que con eso debe ser suficiente para solucionar tu problema. Te dejo un enlace: [Create Trigger (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar la propiedad:

> @@IDENTITY

Para poder obtener el id del producto creado de la siguiente forma:

```
  DECLARE @IdProducto AS INT
     INSERT INTO producto (Nombre,Precio) VALUES ('xbox360', 21500)
     SET @IdProducto = @@IDENTITY   
     UPDATE Producto 
SET tipoproducto = 'PROD'+CAST(@IdProducto AS VARCHAR(MAX)) WHERE id= @IdProducto
```

No olvides castear un variable @IdProducto ya que si no te dara error.

[image: y el resultado seria este]

Answer (score 3):

Puede que haya más de un camino pero, de acuerdo a cómo lo describes, quizás lo siguiente pueda ayudarte.

Desde SQL Server: No necesitas hacer nada del lado del cliente. Sin embargo, deberás crear un **Trigger** que se dispare después de realizar el insert en la tabla, para **crear e insertar el código que deseas automáticamente**.

Dentro del Trigger hay tablas virtuales que contienen los valores que se insertan/actualizan/eliminan. Necesitarás el valor de la llave primaria (en caso que haya una relación uno a uno entre la llave primaria y el código que deseas implementar, es decir, la llave 1 le corresponde 'PROD001'). Puedes obtenerlo mediante

```
Select MAX(IdProducto)
```

o

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

o incluso (dentro del trigger, utilizando la tabla virtual 'inserted'):

```
Select IdProducto from inserted
```

Luego, en el trigger, puedes insertar el valor del código en la columna que desees. El siguiente sql te puede ayudar a obtener el valor:

```
SELECT CONCAT('PROD',  RIGHT('000'+CAST(IdProducto as Varchar(10)),3))
```

Si no utilizas SQL Server 2012 (concat no está disponible antes de esta versión), puedes utilizar:

```
SELECT  'PROD' + RIGHT('000'+CAST(IdProducto as Varchar(10)),3)
```

Y luego insertas ese valor en la columna *Codigo*, que es donde pondrás tu código personalizado.

Saludos

Comment: Buenas, gracias por responder, porque se tiene que hacer con un triggers? No entendi mucho

Comment: No **tiene** que hacerse con un trigger. Pero, es una de las maneras más sencillas y prácticas. Se disparará automáticamente en cada inserción. Si utilizas un ORM(Entity Framework), no caerás en el error n+1 porque sólo harás un insert a la base de datos, no necesitarás hacer un update después.

Si utilizas un procedimiento almacenado, puedes utilizar la respuesta de Jacobo, no hay ningún problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, si para insertar desde el Visual Studio utilizo un procedimiento almacenado